# Number different coloring of Tetrahedron with 2 black and 2 white colors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polya-counting-theory

How to count Number different coloring of Tetrahedron with 2 black and 2 white colors by Bernside lemma. first I count the number ways of choosing 2 and 2 faces, it is $\frac{4!}{2!2!}$. second rotation by one face and one vertice, we have 4 that rotation with order 2, and it is have 1 fixed point. And we have rotation by 2 edges, 3 such rotation with order 1, and 0 fixed points. finally $(1*6+ 8*1+3*0)\frac{1}{12}$. where i have a mistake?

Comment: The eight rotations of order $3$ have no fixed points, and the three of order two each have $2$ fixed points (color each face pair that gets exchanged the same color -- switch colors for the other fixed point), so you get $1$ orbit, which is not hard to see if you think about a tetrahedron. Any pair of the four faces is like any other pair.

Comment: thank you, but how to calculate a fixed points. I thought a fixed points it is faces who don't move. in rotation it is face opposite to vertice.

Comment: Given a rotation, the fixed colorings for that rotation are the colorings which are transformed into themselves by the given rotation. So, e.g. the identity rotation fixes all ($6$) colorings, the $120$ degree rotations around an altitude don't fix any colorings since the stationary face keeps it's color $C$ but the other face of color $C$ gets rotated to a face of the opposite color. The three symmetries of order two exchange two pairs of faces e.g. $(w,x)(y,z)$ which fixes the two colorings ($w,x$=black; $y,z$=white) and ($w,x$=white; $y,z$=black).